# Android Listview Fill from SQL with loop

Tags: android, listview

I trying to populate a listview with data from an SQL database using the following code

```
    final DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
    db.open();  
    Cursor c = db.getAsset6("MARK BARR");
    int mx=1;
    String[] lvdata = new String[mx];


    while (c.moveToNext()) {
    lvdata[mx]=c.getString(1) + "-" + c.getString(2) + "-" + c.getString(6);
    mx++;
    }


    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lvdata));
    getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    db.close();
```

When I run the app crashes I'm am sure it something to do with the way i'm adding the data into a string in the while loop and then setting the adapter but I cant work out where I'm going wrong

Any help is appreciated

Mark

EDIT

OK the following works OK now But he app crashed when I reach the last listview entry

```
    final DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
    db.open();  
    Cursor c = db.getAsset6("MARK BARR");
    int mx=0;
    String[] lvdata = new String[c.getCount()];


    while (c.moveToNext()) {
    lvdata[mx]=c.getString(1) + "-" + c.getString(2) + "-" + c.getString(6);
    mx++;
    }
    // use your custom layout
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        R.layout.rowlayout, R.id.label, lvdata);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
  }
```

Comment: may i ask why don't you use a SimpkeCursorAdapter?

Comment: whats happened to ravi's coment he was really helpful

Comment: as I said pskink im very new to this and still leanring would love an easier way to query my database and put it into a listview

Comment: I have edited the main code above using a turorial on vogella on simple list adapters and this works ok still misses the first record but the app crashes when I scroll to the last entry. I am running a db from the sdcard so I cant test in eclipse when is happening any ideas??

Comment: Guys I worked it out i ws getting a null pointer on the last entries changed the following  String[] lvdata = new String[c.getCount()-1]; and works great thanks for all your help particularly Ravi

Answer (score 0):

Well I am probably not worthy of even tying Vogella's shoes but this how I do it. I like using CursorAdapter because it allows you do all kinds of things with images and I think it's easier. If if you don't use this please check it out as you may need this in the future. Put this where you want to view the data whether in onCreate or from some button being pushed.

```
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = controller.getReadableDatabase();

String query = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM YOURTABLENAME";
Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);

((ListView) YOURLISTVIEWNAME).setAdapter(new ANYNAMEADAPTER(context,
                    cursor, 0));
```

Then we create ANYNAMEADAPTER to get all the data into one organized place

```
 private static final class ANYNAMEADAPTER extends CursorAdapter {

    ANYNAMEADAPTER(Context context, Cursor cursor, int flags) {
        super(context, cursor, flags);

        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = mInflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    TextView theline = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    String thedata =cursor.getString(1) + "-" + cursor.getString(2) + "-" + cursor.getString(6); 
    theline.setText(thedata);
    }

    LayoutInflater mInflater;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this would like to try but am unsure how to implement I am using a db on my sd card using the following : final String appPath = String.format
          (
              "%s/DataFiles", Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
          );
        final String jobsfilepath = appPath + "/maxjobs.db"; how to I implemnet this with your line SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = controller.getReadableDatabase();